# How to move around a long line in vim

Tags: vim

I am currently checking a file with extremely long line, take around 100 screen line to show. When I use page down, it just run directly to next line, how should I page down a screen page?

Answer (score 5):

You can use 'gj' instead of 'j' to move down one displayed line, rather than one line in the file. I'm not sure that vim has any specific concept of a 'screen page', but you could easily move multiple displayed lines at once.

For example, to move down 30 displayed lines: '30gj'.

To move up instead: '30gk'.

Alternatively you could 'scroll' by moving the cursor right and left, eg. '1000l', '1000h'.

You've done well to find something that vim doesn't do very easily, but I hope this helps and you can work out something that works for you.